# Deploying GWT app from GAE to Tomcat

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, tomcat

After deploying I get the message "GWT module 'library' may need to be (re)compiled". The resulting page doesn't contain the text fields and the buttons, which I determined in my java-gwt code. So I assume I've done something wrong while forming the .war file, which I deploy to Tomcat. 
I have been following these instructions https://wiki.auckland.ac.nz/display/BeSTGRID/Deploying+GWT+to+Tomcat+in+Eclipse

It says in the first line: "Make sure your project has been complied using the GWT compiler". 
Well, I've selected the "GWT Compile". After compilation my var directory contains many .cash.html files. I make jar and run the ant build file (which I also took from the mentioned source). After all I deploy the project to Tomcat and get the error :^(

Comment: Rename .war to .zip, unzip it and check that all needed files are inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use eclipse, did you try to export directly to a War File ?

right click on your project > export > web > war file

I proceed like this, and it works !

If you cannot select this option, try to see in your project setting if you checked "dynamic web module" in the facets.

If it's not enough, have a look in your setting in "google > web application"

check the "this project has war directory" and "launch from this directory"

Answer (score 0):

Simple Copy & Paste All **War Folder** Contents of your GWT Application to the Apache Application Folder under /webapps. This will do the trick. No Need to generate a file with war extension.